# AWS CloudWatch Logs Insight Nested Json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

My json log object is like this.

```
{
    "FileName":"file1.xlsx",
    "IsSuccess":false,
    "LogList":[
        {"ErrorDetail":"Text1"},
        {"ErrorDetail":"Text2"},
        {"ErrorDetail":"Text3"},
    ]
}
```

When I write the query in CloudWatch Logs Insight like below it list the nested json in a single line.
**fields @timestamp, FileName, LogList.ErrorDetail**:

[LogsInsight Query Result Nested Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UUGG.png)

[LogsInsight Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSm5X.png)

This makes very difficult to read as the user need to scroll horizontally. I want the list to be displayed veritically. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems no way to do so.